# Change semicolon seperated MERGEFIELD to list

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

Is there a way to format the information from a MERGEFIELD into a human readable list?

**Input**

item1;item2;item3;

**Output**

- item1
- item2
- item3

or

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Answer (score 0):

Mailmerges cannot replace characters in a mergefield with other characters and/or formatting; that would have to be done pre-merge by splitting the data into separate fields so each element can be processed in its own right in the mailmerge main document, or post-merge (e.g. using Find/Replace).